# How to extract whole line text using regex?

Tags: c#, regex

i have a following piece of text i need a regular expression which give me the complete text of that line which starts from `dhcp pool` For e.g. first line starts from dhcp pool so i need complete text of it.Can anyone tell me how to achieve this ,it would be very helpful to me.

```
dhcp pool IT-test
IP address is 12.0.0.0,Network mask is 255.0.0.0
DHCP client node type : 0
Lease  day:1, hour: 0, minute :0
dhcp pool QA-Test
IP address is 192.168.100.0,Network mask is 255.255.255.0
DHCP client node type : 0
Lease  day:1, hour: 0, minute :0
dhcp pool firmware-test
IP address is 11.0.0.0,Network mask is 255.0.0.0
DHCP client node type : 0
Lease  day:1, hour: 0, minute :0
```

2nd piece of code:

```
 string pattern = "/^dhcp pool.*/g";
            Console.WriteLine(pattern);
            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(_str, pattern);

            foreach(Match match in matches)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("+++++++++++++dhcp pool is ++++++++++++++" + match.Groups[1].Value);
                DHCPoolName = match.Groups[1].Value;
            }
```

XAML code:

```
<ComboBox
            Grid.Column="1"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Margin="0,4"
            ItemsSource="{Binding DHCPoolName}">              
        </ComboBox>
```

Comment: *^/$ Anchors*: `^dhcp pool(.*)$`

Comment: Or you can use `String.StartsWith("dhcp pool")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you could use the below regex

```
^dhcp pool.*
```

The above regex would match all the lines which starts with `dhcp pool` . `^` asserts that we are at the start. `.*` matches any character except line breaks zero or more times.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/jL4eP9/3)

Comment: It worked !!But one more thing which i want to ask is that after getting complete line which starts from dhcp test i want to bind that line to my WPF combobox .I am editing the above code please give me answer to this question.